# Mixed content and insecure favicon

Tags: javascript, passport-local

I am trying to submit a login form so whenever I write username and password it should redirect me to the homepage it just pops up this error message

"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plump-otter.glitch.me/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://glitch.com/favicon-app.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I have tried to change url to full https url as shown in error message but doesn't work..I have included my server.js file and also index file

```
'use strict';

const express     = require('express');
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const fccTesting  = require('./freeCodeCamp/fcctesting.js');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient();
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');


const app = express();

fccTesting(app); //For FCC testing purposes
app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use(session({

  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUnintialized: true,

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongo.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, (err, db) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Database error: '+err);


  } else {

  console.log('Successful database connection');

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user._id);

});




 passport.deserializeUser( (id, done) => {

  db.collection('users').findOne(

      {_id: new ObjectID(id)},
      (err, doc) => {

        done(null, doc);


      }
  );

});
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done) {
      db.collection('users').findOne({ username: username}, function(err, user) {
        console.log("User "+username +" attempted to log in.");
        if(err){return done(err);}
        if(!user){ return done(null, false);}
        if(password !== user.password) {return done(null, false); }
        return done(user, null);
  });
  }
));


  app.route('/')
   .get((req, res) => {


    res.render(process.cwd() + '/views/pug/index', {title: 'Hello',message: 'Please login', showLogin: true});
  });
    app.route('/login')
    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/'}),
     function(req, res) {


    res.redirect('/profile');

    });

    app.route('/profile')
    .get((req, res) => {
      res.render(process.cwd() + '/profile');

    });

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port " + process.env.PORT);

});

}});
```

My index file

```
html
  head
    title FCC Advanced Node and Express
    meta(name='description', content='A cool thing made with HyperDev')
    link#favicon(rel='icon', href='https://hyperdev.com/favicon-app.ico', type='image/x-icon')
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/public/style.css')
  body
    h1.border.center FCC Advanced Node and Express
    h2.center#pug-success-message
    | Looks like this page is being rendered from Pug into HTML!
    | {Home Page}
    p#pug-variable= message



    if showLogin
      hr
      p Login Form
      form(action='/login', method='post')
        div
          label Username:
          input(type='text', name='username')
        div
          label Password:
          input(type='password', name='password')
        div
          input(type='submit', value='Log In')

    if showRegistration
      hr
      p Registration Form
      form(action='/register', method='post')
        div
          label Username:
          input(type='text', name='username')
        div
          label Password:
          input(type='password', name='password')
        div
          input(type='submit', value='Register')


    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js', integrity='sha256-gvQgAFzTH6trSrAWoH1iPo9Xc96QxSZ3feW6kem+O00=', crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='/public/client.js')
```

Comment: You do not HAVE a favicon in that location. try loading https://hyperdev.com/favicon-app.ico and you get an 404 html page from glitch

Comment: The glitch favicon is here: https://cdn.gomix.com/2bdfb3f8-05ef-4035-a06e-2043962a3a13%2Ffavicon.ico

Comment: I have installed favicon-express dependency on my package.json file on glitch server and then import this dependency to my server.js file and use it but still give me the same error???

Answer (score 0):

When I visited the URL of your favicon, the image couldn't be found.
But a better way to serve favicon with express is to use **express-favicon** which serves the favicon to all your pages without you defining it on each page.
To install

```
npm install express-favicon
```

And this is how to use it in code.

```js
var favicon = require('express-favicon');

app.use(favicon('...location of favicon here...'));
```

That's all and no need to do any extra HTML work. but please check your favicon's URL again